# List of Windows 11 File Associations

Tags: windows, file, associations

Is there a way, either searching the registry or using the command line, to generate a list of file Windows 11 file associations?

Ideally, the list would include the application name (i.e. "Notepad"), the associated extensions (i.e. "txt, rtf" etc) and the command line used to call up an item ("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe %1")

I've seen various answers here but many apply to much older versions of Windows.